# How to make scatterplot with nested array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot with the list of coordinates I have. I'm just confused how to separate these coordinates into x and y so that I can plug it into the plt.scatter() function, especially considering it is a nested array of arrays.

```
   array([array([1., 0.]), array([ 0., -1.]), array([-1.,  0.]),
   array([-1., -1.]), array([ 1., -1.]), array([ 0., -2.]),
   array([-2.,  0.]), array([2., 0.]), array([-2., -1.]),
   array([ 2., -1.]), array([-1., -2.]), array([ 1., -2.]),
   array([-2., -2.]), array([ 2., -2.]), array([ 0., -3.]),
   array([3., 0.]), array([-3.,  0.]), array([ 1., -3.]),
   array([-1., -3.]), array([ 3., -1.]), array([-3., -1.]),
   array([-2., -3.]), array([ 3., -2.]), array([-3., -2.]),
   array([ 2., -3.]), array([-4.,  0.]), array([4., 0.]),
   array([-4., -1.]), array([ 4., -1.]), array([-3., -3.]),
   array([ 3., -3.]), array([ 4., -2.]), array([-4., -2.]),
   array([ 4., -3.]), array([-4., -3.]), array([-1., -5.]),
   array([ 1., -5.]), array([-5., -1.]), array([-5., -2.]),
   array([-5., -3.]), array([ 3., -5.]), array([-3., -5.]),
   array([-6.,  0.]), array([-6., -1.]), array([-6., -2.]),
   array([-6., -3.]), array([-5., -5.]), array([-7., -1.]),
   array([ 1., -7.]), array([-1., -7.]), array([-7., -2.]),
   array([-3., -7.]), array([-7., -3.]), array([ 3., -7.]),
   array([-7., -5.]), array([-5., -7.]), array([-1., -9.]),
   array([ 1., -9.]), array([ 3., -9.]), array([-3., -9.]),
   array([-7., -7.]), array([-5., -9.]), array([  1., -11.]),
   array([ -1., -11.]), array([ -3., -11.]), array([  3., -11.]),
   array([-7., -9.]), array([ -5., -11.]), array([ -7., -11.])],
  dtype=object)
```

Comment: Does `x,y = np.array(my_data).T; plt.scatter(x,y)` help?

Comment: Maybe `np.array(my_data, dtype=float).T` to get rid of that pesky `dtype=object`?

Comment: Does `np.stack` help?

Comment: When I try transposing, it says 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

Comment: Pay close attention to what you have.  What's the `shape`?  The dtype is object.  To make a scatter plot you need a (n,2) array, with `float` dtype.  If the shape is 1d (e.g. (69,)), then `np.stack(arr)` should work.  Transposing a 1d object array does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.array([
    0,
    np.array([0.,  3.]),
    np.array([2., 4.]),
    np.array([-3., -1.]),
    np.array([-4.,  2.]),
    np.array([2., 0.]),
    np.array([-2., -2.])
], dtype=object)[1:]
print(repr(arr))
```

prints:

```
array([array([0., 3.]), array([2., 4.]), array([-3., -1.]),
       array([-4.,  2.]), array([2., 0.]), array([-2., -2.])],
      dtype=object)
```

then you can use `np.stack` (as others have already suggested in the comments) to convert `arr` to a 2d-array:

```
arr = np.stack(arr)
print(repr(arr))
```

which prints:

```
array([[ 0.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [-3., -1.],
       [-4.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  0.],
       [-2., -2.]])
```

and is much easier to plot:

```
plt.scatter(arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1])
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it says: 'IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed'

Comment: MIchael, when you print your `arr`, does it show nesting arrays as the OP's does?  If it is a 2d float array, then you did not replicate his case,

Comment: hpaulj thanks for pointing this out. It indeed did not replicate OP's case, but now I think it does.